# VB.NET For Each

Tags: vb.net, hash, foreach, md5

After finally fixing my last problem, the code that I ended with was

```
Function MD5(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5Obj As New Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

    Dim strResult As String = ""

    For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
        strResult += b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return strResult
End Function



Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    For Each word As String In words
        If String.Equals(MD5(word), hash.Text) Then
            Label2.Text = word
        Else : Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
        End If
    Next
```

Now I need to make it stop once the hashed word matches the hash I typed in!

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ's [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), since you're using `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` anyway:

```
Dim firstWord = (From line In IO.File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Where String.Equals(MD5(line), hash.Text)).FirstOrDefault()
If firstWord IsNot Nothing Then
    Label2.Text = firstWord 
Else
    Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
End If
```

Another way is a simple loop:

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim matchingLine As String = Nothing
For i = 0 To lines.Length -1
    Dim line = lines(i)
    If String.Equals(MD5(line), hash.Text)) Then 
        matchingLine = line
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If matchingLine IsNot Nothing Then
    Label2.Text = matchingLine 
Else
    Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
End If
```

Comment: It needs to be in a for loop because the file they are opening has multiple lines.

Comment: @user1328301: LINQ is executing this in a loop, even if it doesn't look like this. The loop will be exited as soon as a  line matches the where-condition, because of the  `FirstOrDefault`. But you need at least .NET 3.5 for LINQ.

Comment: @user1328301: i've added the non-linq way, just for the sake of completess.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a loop, use `Exit For`:

```
Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

For Each word As String In words
    If MD5(word) = hash.Text Then
        Label2.Text = word
        Exit For
    Else : Label2.Text = "Hash Could Not Be Cracked"
    End If
Next
```

But note that the `Else` makes no sense here (the form won’t be updated until after the method is left) and that `String.Equals` can be replaced here by `=` (I’ve already done that).